# Textbox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to bind `TextBox` to object property and I can't make it work.

I tried this two uses and neither works:

```
 <TextBox Name="textBoxZbozi" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1" 
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Artikl_CODE, ElementName=vybranyRadek}" />

 <TextBlock Name="textBlockArtikl" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="1" 
          Text="{Binding Path=vybranyRadek.Artikl_NAME}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

viewModel:

```
private Radek vybranyRadek;
public Radek VybranyRadek
{
    get
    {
        return this.vybranyRadek;
    }
    set
    {
        this.vybranyRadek = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("VybranyRadek");
    }
}
```

and `Radek` class:

```
public class Radek
    {
        public bool ZASKRTNUTO { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Artikl_ID { get; set; }
        public string Artikl_NAME { get; set; }
        public string Artikl_CODE { get; set; }
        public string Sarze_ID { get; set; }
        public string Sarze_NAME { get; set; }
        public string Sarze_POPIS { get; set; }
        public string Umisteni_ID { get; set; }
        public string Umisteni_NAME { get; set; }
        public double Mnozstvi { get; set; }
        public string Jednotka { get; set; }
}
```

`vybranyRadek` should be created and filled with some data. This is how I assign data:

```
Radek temp = ((Radek)dataGrid.SelectedItem);
viewModel.VybranyRadek = temp;
```

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: Where do you assign the datacontext, do you assign it at all?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt include it, but  `this.DataContext = viewModel;` is in `Window` constructor

Comment: `vybranyRadek` should be the first letter capital `VybranyRadek`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxZbozi" Text="{Binding VybranyRadek.Artikl_CODE}" />
```

Please be aware that WPF bindings are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was the first capital letter

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you used "vybranyRadek" in your Binding, but that is the member name. You have to use "VybranyRadek". Second issue, is that in the first Binding you used "ElementName". If the ViewModel that contains the property is the DataContext of both TextBlocks, you don`t have to use that. Simply use:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxZbozi" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1" 
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding VybranyRadek.Artikl_CODE}" />

<TextBlock Name="textBlockArtikl" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="1" 
               Text="{Binding VybranyRadek.Artikl_NAME}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the capital first letter